# Homebrew install issue

Tags: xcode, installation, homebrew

I have installed xcode

```
xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

After this I did brew update

```
brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

Then brew doctor gave the following error

```
brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers 
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: No developer tools installed.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install

Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/llnode.rb
undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass
Error: Cannot tap homebrew/core: invalid syntax in tap!
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core -q
```

I have already re-installed homebrew but it did not help.

Pasting my brew config

```
brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.2.2
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 54e01d76db34a3a649c79b189873bfd0a52dbc9f
Last commit: 8 days ago
Core tap: N/A
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.0.0-p648
Clang: N/A
Git: 2.11.0 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_131
macOS: 10.12.4-x86_64
Xcode: N/A
CLT: N/A
X11: N/A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because of wrong xcode installation.
I reinstalled xcode and homebrew again and it worked fine.
Don't know why xcode error was not there while using it .